# Hibernate remvoves all cached objects from second level cache when insert query is failed or when excpetion occures - how to prevent it.please suggest

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, second-level-cache

Hibernate removes all cached objects from second level cache when insert query is failed or when exception occurres - how to prevent it.please suggest

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Without it, how do you expect to us to help you? Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Adding Example :

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Response createOrUpdateRouting(Routing request) {
`Transaction tr = null;`

    appLog = AppLog.getAppLog();

    response = new Response();

if (null != this.sessionFactory) {
session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
} else if (this.sessionFactory == null) {
sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
}
try {
tr = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(request);
response.setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);
response.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
if(null != request && request.getId() > 0){
response.setResponseMsg(Constants.UPDATE_MSG);
}else{
response.setResponseMsg(Constants.SUCESS_MSG);
}
session.flush();
tr.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
tr.rollback();
appLog.error("Exception occurred in createOrUpdateRouting", ex);
response.setStatus(Status.FAILURE);
response.setResponseCode(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
response.setResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
} finally { 
session.close();
}
return response;
}
```